# USB-Serial Driver(Exar Xr21v1414) Run Error

Tags: linux, compiling, drivers, usb, c

I'm currently trying to run the bellow driver in linux-3.8.3 on Exar xr21v1414
 http://www.exar.com/connectivity/uart-and-bridging-solutions/usb-uarts/xr21v1410,
but when i install the driver vizzini.ko, it arise the follow error:

```
[  162.650000] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for Vizzini USB serial port
[  162.650000] vizzini 1-1.4:1.0: Vizzini USB serial port converter detected
[  162.660000] usb 1-1.4: Vizzini USB serial port converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[  162.670000] vizzini 1-1.4:1.1: Zero length descriptor references
[  162.670000] vizzini: probe of 1-1.4:1.1 failed with error -22
[  162.680000] vizzini 1-1.4:1.2: Vizzini USB serial port converter detected
[  162.690000] usb 1-1.4: Vizzini USB serial port converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[  162.690000] vizzini 1-1.4:1.3: Zero length descriptor references
[  162.700000] vizzini: probe of 1-1.4:1.3 failed with error -22
[  162.710000] vizzini 1-1.4:1.4: Vizzini USB serial port converter detected
[  162.710000] usb 1-1.4: Vizzini USB serial port converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[  162.720000] vizzini 1-1.4:1.5: Zero length descriptor references
[  162.730000] vizzini: probe of 1-1.4:1.5 failed with error -22
[  162.730000] vizzini 1-1.4:1.6: Vizzini USB serial port converter detected
[  162.740000] usb 1-1.4: Vizzini USB serial port converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[  162.750000] vizzini 1-1.4:1.7: Zero length descriptor references
[  162.750000] vizzini: probe of 1-1.4:1.7 failed with error -22
```

I would greatly appreciate any help in resolving the errors.

Answer (score 1):

It seems latest vizzini driver supports kernel versions <= 3.4.x

Update: now vizzini driver supports 3.5.x and newer kernels.